# Send USSD String

Tags: at-command

I am writing an application to send ussd commands, retrieve a menu and then send through an option.

When I run the command

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*120*105#",15
```

I receive a menu back, however how do I select one of the options using AT commands.

For example option 1

I am testing using Hyper terminal on Windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Answer

You send the option followed by Control-Z

Eg 1 Control-Z